# SQL select resultOfSelect from table

Tags: sql

I’m a beginner to SQL and am struggling with the following:

I have two tables with the same columns except one column from table A is not a column of table B and table B has a column that table A doesn’t have. I want to copy data from
one into the other table.

I got the following SQL, that gives me the column-names of my table B:

```
SELECT name 
FROM sys.columns 
WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(’TABLEB’) 
  AND name <> COLUMNNOTINA
```

I want to use that select as a query:

```
SELECT 
    (SELECT name 
     FROM sys.columns 
     WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(’TABLEB’) 
       AND name <> COLUMNNOTINA), 0 
FROM 
    TABLEA
```

This does not work, but how do I make this work?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Your question is not very clear, but it sounds like you are trying to dynamically build your query?  If so, that's a long way from beginning sql.

Answer (score 0):

**Let's say there is some common thing connecting the two tables**
For example, ORDINAL_POSITION

```
T1.ORDINAL_POSITION = T2.ORDINAL_POSITION
```

Is there a description or property to compare each column?

```
select * from (
(SELECT name FROM sys.columns WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(’TABLEA’) ) as T1
Inner join 
(SELECT name FROM sys.columns WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(’TABLEB’) ) as T2
ON T1.ORDINAL_POSITION = T2.ORDINAL_POSITION
)
Where T1.ColName <> T2.ColName
```